# Template helpers not working after meteor update

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I updated my Meteor from v0.8, to latest 1.0, and one of the issues I encountered was that normal template helpers stopped working, as in:

This used to work:

```
Template.allCustomers.helpers({  
    getAllCustomers: function(filter) {    
        return Customers.find(filter, {sort: {registered: -1 }  });
    },
```

when called like:

```
Template.allCustomers.getAllCustomers();
```

..but after the update it didnt. So I looked it up into the Template.allCustomers object, and found that by calling it like this it works:

```
Template.allCustomers.__helpers.get("getAllCustomers")()
```

So my question is, is this the actual intention? Seems like it was uselessly complicated. I tried to search documentation on templating changes but could not locate and understand:

- why was this change made
- where is the improvement.

Thanks,

Comment: that's an implementation detail to escape helpers with reserved names. The original syntax `Template.allCustomers.helper({...})` should still work according to docs?

Comment: Oh, the question has changed. You can still extract the helper into a separate function though.

Comment: hello, yes sorry my initial question was incomplete; hope now it makes more sense what I mean. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "extract the helper into a separate function"?

Comment: instead of calling it as `Template.allCustomers.getAllCustomers()`, extract the method to a separate file-scoped function called `getAllCustomers`. And then put it into helpers `Template.allCustomers.helper({getAllCustomers:getAllCustomers});` and then call it by name `getAllCustomers()`.

Comment: allright i did what you said and it works fine; but, if I added now like a standalone function, do I really need to declare it as a helper anymore? Since I just call it directly. getAllCustomers(). Anyway, onwards to refactoring! If u want add the advice above as answer so I can give credit. thx

Comment: You should only add a function as a helper if you intend on calling it from your HTML template code.